# Find a string in Excel and store the column letter in a variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the string "TOTAL" in the first row in each sheet in a workbook and write those column letters in a new sheet.

This is what I got so far. I can find the string and obtain the column letter and show it in a message Box.  I tried to store the result in a variable, however I can't figure out how to write the variable back in a already existing sheet.

```
Sub Find()
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim strToFind As String
    Dim addCell As Range
    
    strToFind = "TOTAL"
    With Worksheets("Stand.1").UsedRange
        Set rngResult = .Find(What:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
        
        If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAddress As String, result As String
            firstAddress = rngResult.Address
        Do
            result = result & rngResult.Address & ","
            Set rngResult = .FindNext(rngResult)
            Loop While rngResult.Address <> firstAddress
                output = Mid(result, 2, 1)
                MsgBox "Found """ & strToFind & """ in column: " & output
                Set addCell = Worksheets("Stand.1").Range(.Address)
                End If
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to be honest. What do you plan to do with the column letter?

Comment: It indeed is - it's an attempt of solving another problem I have dealt with for some time. 
I have a workbook with a lot of sheets containing a different number of columns. The second last column in each sheet is the TOTAL column. I'm trying to insert a varying number of empty columns before the TOTAL column in each sheet, such that the "TOTAL" column is in the same position(column) in each sheet. My thought was to change the column letter to a number, and then comparing the numbers(positions) of the TOTAL column for each sheet, to know exactly how many empty columns is needed in each sheet.

Comment: I have the "insert columns"-part working. But I don't know how to automate the "insert 1 columns in sheet1, 8 columns in sheet2, 0 columns in sheet3, and so on"-part. That's what I'm trying to solve splitting the problem into smaller parts and using different approaches until it works as intended.

Comment: then you do not need to get the letter as you can directly make it a number:  `output = Application.Match("Total",Worksheets("Stand.1").Range("1:1"),0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adjust Totals (Columns)

- The following will loop trough the worksheets, of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`). It will skip the worksheets whose names are in the `Exceptions Array`.
- For each worksheet it will try to find the string "TOTAL" in the first row (header row) and will write the name of the worksheet to the first, and the column number to the second column of `Data Array`.
- At the same time it will calculate the largest column number (`MaxColumn`).
- Using the values collected in `Data Array`, it will insert empty columns to adjust the `Totals Column` to the same (max column) in each worksheet, e.g. all worksheets might have the `Totals Column` in Column `Z`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustTotals()
    
    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const hTitle As String = "TOTAL"
    ' The Exceptions Array contains the names of the worksheets you want
    ' to exclude from the adjustment.
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("Sheet728") ' add more
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    ' First column for worksheet name, second for totals column number.
    ReDim Data(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
    
    ' Additional variables for the upcoming 'For Each Next' loop.
    Dim ws As Worksheet          ' Current Worksheet
    Dim CurrentValue As Variant  ' Current Totals Column Number
    Dim MaxColumn As Long        ' Max Column Number
    Dim i As Long                ' Data Array Row Counter
    
    ' Write worksheet name and total column number to Data Array and
    ' define Max Column Number.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If UBound(Exceptions) >= LBound(Exceptions) Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
                GoTo NextWorksheet
            End If
        End If
        CurrentValue = Application.Match(hTitle, ws.Rows(hRow), 0)
        If Not IsError(CurrentValue) Then
            i = i + 1
            Data(i, 1) = ws.Name
            Data(i, 2) = CurrentValue
            If CurrentValue > MaxColumn Then
                MaxColumn = CurrentValue
            End If
        End If
NextWorksheet:
    Next ws
                
    ' Insert columns using the values from Data Array..
    For i = 1 To i
        If Data(i, 2) < MaxColumn Then
            wb.Worksheets(Data(i, 1)).Columns(Data(i, 2)) _
              .Resize(, MaxColumn - Data(i, 2)).Insert
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Total columns adjusted.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: @User123456789: I see you have asked another question about this. You could replace `"TOTAL"` with `"TOT*"` or `"TOTA*"` or `"TOTAL*"` or `"TOTAL.*"` and the code should work. `Match` does accept wild characters like `*` and `?`. Off course, it is always better to get more than one solution (opinion).